# how do I determine a ranking from votes by multiple members of a group

Tags: regression, ranking

I'm having 8 members of a group choose their favorite 12 items from a list in order from 1 to 12.  How do I analyze their data and determine the group items' ranking from 1 to 12 ?  1 is most favorite and 12 is least.

Comment: This is for a singing group choosing 12 songs from a list of 30 to determine a 12 song list for the group to learn.  Each person ranks their chosen ones from 1(favorite) to 12 (least favorite).  How do I extract the winning 12 from the 8 ranked choices?

Comment: There are multiple ways of computing a single, global ranking for the group, based on rankings assigned by each individual. This is called a [ranked voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_voting) system, and is used for elections in various countries. See the Wikipedia article for some example algorithms. Also see [Arrow's impossibility theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem) for an interesting theoretical result.